# Alternative to PayPal for Merchant Services, Instant Transfer and Immediate Accessibility by Debit Card

Tags: api, payment-processing

I have a scenario where an application processes a payment and sends a portion of the payment to other providers. Part of the allure of PayPal is that these funds are available immediately via their PayPal Debit Card.

Are there any alternatives that offer an API for performing these transactions? I've seen mention of alternatives for this scenario (for example, in the following thread on the Dwolla site), but have never actually seen a company mentioned.

https://discuss.dwolla.com/t/will-dwolla-add-credit-cards-like-paypal/62

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at: https://stripe.com/connect.  It looks like it handles payment collection as well as sending payments to other providers. I've never used it myself though.